# Cambiar imagenes de un groupbox con un click en un picturebox en C#

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes.

Necesito su ayuda por favor. Soy estudiante de informática y estoy haciendo un proyecto de sistema de ventas de comida rápida.

En el programa tengo en un form, en el diseñador 2 groupbox y un datagridview, en el primer groupbox tengo 4 picturebox con imágenes de hamburguesas, jugos, postres y pizzas.

El problema es el siguiente: cuando yo le de un click en uno de los picture box me muestre en el segundo groupbox imagenes de las opciones del producto.

Que cada vez que yo le de click en hamburguesas o jugos o pizzas me muestre en el segundo groupbox las opciones de productos pero que tambien sean picturebox

Les agradecería su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que bueno que agregaste un imagen que ilustra a donde quieres llegar, ahora necesitas agregar tu codigo actual para que te podamos orientar mejor

Answer (score 0):

A falta de ver el código lo que necesitas es capturar el evento Click de las picureBox del primer grupo y en ese evento rellenar las pictureBox del segundo grupo con las imágenes que quieras.

**EDITADO**

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo muy simple en el que supongo que las imágenes están agregadas como recursos

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.pictureBox1Group1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1Group2.Image = Resources.Image1;
        pictureBox2Group2.Image = Resources.Image2;
        pictureBox3Group2.Image = Resources.Image3;
        pictureBox4Group2.Image = Resources.Image4;
    }
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: me pueden proporcionar codigo por fabor es lo que necesito

Comment: Ok Edito el comentario con un ejemplo muy simple.

Comment: deacuerdo a tu codigo @Gerardo, solo con hacer click el el primner picturebox asiganra automaticamente todas las imagenes a los picturebox del 2do grupo...supongo que lo que el quiere es que  se asignen en el primer picturebox que este vacio a medida que valla haciendo click en los picturebox del primer grupo

Comment: Entendí que con cada click en el primer grupo cambiaban las 4 del segundo, si no es así, danos mas detalles @josemiguelhuertasrodas y lo vemos